# MySQL select multiple id at the same time with optional id with php

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-rank

I would like to complicate this request by changing the scenario.
Here is the link to the original request.
[Here is the link to the original request.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570455/mysql-select-multiple-id-at-the-same-time-with-php/)

I have the following MySQL table called skills.

| id | idUser | idSkill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 8 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 | 9 |
| 4 | 13 | 9 |
| 5 | 18 | 2 |
| 6 | 22 | 1 |
| 7 | 27 | 2 |
| 8 | 32 | 4 |
| 9 | 11 | 2 |
| 10 | 32 | 9 |
| 10 | 32 | 7 |

I need to select, for example, all idUsers that have idSkill 4 and 9 at the same time (mandatory skills).

But I would like to have the possibility to search by optional idSkills (if any).

Mandatory skills are 9 and 4

Optional skill is 7

The result would be idUser 32.

I thought of this query:

```
SELECT id, idUser, idSkill FROM skills WHERE idSkill IN (9,4,7) GROUP BY idUser HAVING (idSkill IN (9,4))
```

But it clearly does not work.

Many thanks

Comment: If you want faster answers, provide a db fiddle.  So you want HAVING both, instead of one in the list?

Comment: @forpas No would not be in the results

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34353369/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60583112/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation and `RANK()` window function.

This query:

```
SELECT idUser
FROM skills 
WHERE idSkill IN (9, 4, 7) 
GROUP BY idUser 
HAVING SUM(idSkill IN (9, 4)) = 2 -- for the 2 mandatory skills
```

returns all the users with at least the 2 mandatory skills 9 and 4.

If you use an `ORDER BY` clause with `LIMIT` like this:

```
SELECT idUser
FROM skills 
WHERE idSkill IN (9, 4, 7) 
GROUP BY idUser 
HAVING SUM(idSkill IN (9, 4)) = 2 -- for the 2 mandatory skills
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

you will get from all the users with at least the 2 mandatory skills 9 and 4, only 1 user: the one with the largest number of skills (mandatory and optional).

If you want ties returned, use `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT idUser
FROM (
  SELECT idUser, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM skills 
  WHERE idSkill IN (9, 4, 7) 
  GROUP BY idUser 
  HAVING SUM(idSkill IN (9, 4)) = 2 -- for the 2 mandatory skills
) t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a295c4a7fb9adae4da9d4ccb3d596007).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works perfectly.

However, the users and the mandatory and optional skills might vary in my database. Your example is perfect if the data scenario remains the same.

Comment: @nusima I don't understand what the problem is. Of course mandatory and optional skills may vary. All you have to do is change the values in the lists.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to enter a new user that met mandatory skills and optional skills and it did not show up in the selection. I will try again now.

Comment: @nusima can you reproduce it in my demo?

Comment: Here I have inserted a user. It is not displayed even if I delete the optional skill https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=efc590095d60b8cc011e7c0fac7776b1

Comment: @nusima if you use `;` instead of `,` in the VALUES of INSERT, then the statements are ignored. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87dc2d390efdfb3f8f978d9b1d154bfb

Comment: I am a fool. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will be a simple query.

select * from (select distinct b.idUser, (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=4) 'four', (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=9) 'nine', (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=7) 'seven' from skill b) t where t.four=1 and t.nine=1 and t.seven=1

Comment: Where are the optional skills?

Comment: Since it's optional it should not be in the query i guess. if you run the query you can see optional skill also coming.

Comment: for the user id 8 output will be 4.9 and for the user id 32 output will be 4,9,7

Comment: Read the question again and the comments under my answer. The requirement is to return the user(s) with at least the mandatory skills and the most of the optional skills. Your code returns all the users with the mandatory skills which was the requirement of the OP's previous question (link in the question).

Comment: select * from (select distinct b.idUser, (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=4) 'four', (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=9) 'nine', (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=7) 'seven' from skill b) t where t.four=1 and t.nine=1 and t.seven=1

Comment: does it help? please do let me know then will update in answer.

Comment: Your edited code makes skill 7 mandatory although it is optional. So if user 32 does not have skill 7 would not be returned: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4707505939a90b09e8342dcaef71376

Comment: it should be and as per my understanding as you want to apply condition on the set where 4 and 9 exists.  on that if you apply condition = 7 then it must be and. otherwise if you want 4,9 and optional value yes/no then need to use thise code   select * from (select distinct b.idUser, (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=4) 'four', (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=9) 'nine', (select 1 from skill a where a.idUser=b.idUser and a.idSkill=7) 'seven' from skill b) t where (t.four=1 and t.nine=1)  or t.seven=1